# Move 2D Object to a Point in OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, opengl

How to move a 2D object in the direction of a point (not a `GL_POINTS`, but coordinates) using OpenGL?

For a better understanding of my code:

I've splited most of my code into different source codes, but this is the one that is actually creating the shapes and setting the scene:

```
void setupScene(int clearColor[]) {
    glClearColor(clearColor[0], clearColor[1], clearColor[2], clearColor[3]);
    //glClearColor(250, 250, 250, 1.0);  //  Set the cleared screen colour to black.
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);  // This sets up the viewport so that the coordinates (0, 0) are at the top left of the window.
    
    // Set up the orthographic projection so that coordinates (0, 0) are in the top left.
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, -10, 10);
    
    // Back to the modelview so we can draw stuff.
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the screen and depth buffer.
}

void drawScene() {
    setupScene((int[]){250, 250, 250, 1});
    
    triangle(210, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(RGB(80), RGB(80), RGB(80));

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(400, 400, 0);
    glVertex2d(200, 100);
    glVertex2d(100, 100);
    glVertex2d(100, 200);
    glVertex2d(200, 200);
    glPopMatrix();
    glEnd();
    
    glutSwapBuffers();  // Send the scene to the screen.
}

void update(int value) {
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Tell GLUT that the display has changed.
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);  // Tell GLUT to call update again in 25 milliseconds.
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Code-Guru: With a little help I got it working. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you don't really need the push and pop matrix calls.  They are there to isolate an operation or build relative transforms from worldspace.  If you're always working in worldspace, just overwrite the matrix instead.

Comment: @paddy: What you mean is that I only need to use `push` an `pop` if there are other objects in the screen, so they don't interfere with each other? I understood it right? Also, thanks for helping me learn more about OpenGL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to translate the modelview matrix.  Assuming you're in modelview mode already:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
// Draw your shape
glPopMatrix();
```

**[Edit]**

> @paddy: Something like this? I tried this but the square isn't moving.
>   pastebin.com/2PCsy5kC

Try explicitly selecting the modelview matrix.  Your example does not tell us which mode it's currently in:

```
glSetMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(x, y, z);
// Draw your shape
glPopMatrix();
```

Normally at the beginning of your render you reset everything... So you enter the GL_PROJECTION mode, call `glLoadIdentity()` to reset it and set up your camera, then do this for the GL_MODELVIEW matrix as well.

Comment: This is assuming @Nathan is using immediate mode, is it not?

Comment: @TimCooper: No, this works in whatever you call the non-immediate mode.

Comment: @paddy: Something like this? I tried this but the square isn't moving. http://pastebin.com/2PCsy5kC

Comment: @quixoto:  Even when using VBOs?

Comment: @TimCooper: Not sure, haven't used VBOs. My experience is with ES 1.1 using vertex arrays, but I use this pattern all the time and ES doesn't support an immediate mode.

Answer (score 0):

*Answer on the behalf of the OP:*

[Thanks @paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731308/11573842), I was trying to understand the use of `glTranslatef` and came with the solution. Here is the working code, it will create a square at 100x100 and will move it until 400x200:

```
void setupScene(int clearColor[]) {
    glClearColor(clearColor[0], clearColor[1], clearColor[2], clearColor[3]);
    //glClearColor(250, 250, 250, 1.0);  //  Set the cleared screen colour to black.
    glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);  // This sets up the viewport so that the coordinates (0, 0) are at the top left of the window.
    
    // Set up the orthographic projection so that coordinates (0, 0) are in the top left.
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, -10, 10);
    
    // Back to the modelview so we can draw stuff.
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the screen and depth buffer.
}

int a = 100;
int b = 200;
int x = 100;
int y = 100;

void drawScene() {
    setupScene((int[]){250, 250, 250, 1});
    
    triangle(210, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(RGB(80), RGB(80), RGB(80));

    glVertex2d(b, a);
    glVertex2d(a, a);
    glVertex2d(a, b);
    glVertex2d(b, b);

    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    
    glutSwapBuffers();  // Send the scene to the screen.
}

void update(int value) {
    if (x != 400 && y != 200) {
        x += 4;
        y += 2;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();  // Tell GLUT that the display has changed.
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);  // Tell GLUT to call update again in 25 milliseconds.
}
```